# In JavaScript, how can I statically import subclasses in the superclass without hitting ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript, node.js, subclass, extends, referenceerror

I have a base class that is kind of like a "router" to a known set of nodes, where any node can "go to" any other node.  Each node is subclassed from a "base" node with shared methods.

I am having trouble figuring out how to set this up without using Dynamic Imports in JavaScript.

Here's my code ("a" and "b" are the nodes):

**a.js**

```
import Base from "./base.js";

export default class A extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    doAStuff() {
        console.log("doing A stuff");
    }
}
```

**b.js**

```
import Base from "./base.js";

export default class B extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    doBStuff() {
        console.log("doing B stuff");
    }
}
```

**base.js** (the common base class)

```
import A from "./a.js";
import B from "./b.js";

export default class Base {
    constructor() {
    }

    async goToA() {
        console.log("going to A");
        return new A();
    }

    async goToB() {
        console.log("going to B");
        return new B();
    }
}
```

and finally, **index.js**, the node script to run it all -- this starts with "A" and navigates to "B" and then back to "A".

```
import A from "./a.js";

(async () => {
    var a = new A();
    var b = await a.goToB();
    b = await b.goToA();
})();
```

When I run this in Node.JS using `node index.js`, I get the following error:

```
export default class B extends Base {
                               ^
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Base' before initialization
    at file:///Users/asefkow/git3/webclient/SitesCloud/dev/components/testing/b.js:5:32
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:166:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
```

However, if I remove the `import` statements, and instead dynamically import "a" and "b" in `base.js` using code like below, then `node index.js` works.

```
/* jshint esversion: 8, node: true */

export default class Base {
    constructor() {
    }

    async goToA() {
        let {default: A} = await import('./a.js');

        console.log("going to A");
        return new A();
    }

    async goToB() {
        let {default: B} = await import('./b.js');

        console.log("going to B");
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to avoid the dynamic imports here?

Comment: The better way to avoid this is to not have circular dependencies. Your superclass shouldn't need to know which subclasses exist beforehand, so: can you explain what you're _actually_ trying to do here, with concretely named classes and functions? Because it's a good bet you've falling into the XY problem: you're asking about how to fix your solution rather than asking how to solve the original problem that you wrote this class hierarchy for.

Comment: That's a fair request ... this is code for end-to-end automated testing.  The "base" is actually the Main page, with a navigation bar that allows access to child pages A, B, C, etc.  Because the navigation bar appears on all pages, any page can navigate to any other page.  So I want to be able to write code like productPage.goToSearchPage() and, conversely, searchPage.goToProductPage().

Comment: That's called a router: have a class whose sole job it is to accept route registrations, tied to classes (e.g. `static register(route, objectClass) { Router.entries[route] = objectClass; }`) so that you can say `Router.goTo("wherever")` and have it spit out an instance of the class that services that route (e.g. `static goTo(route) { return Router.entries[route] ?? new UnkownPage(); }`). It needs to know nothing about your class hierarchy, all it needs to know is how to service navigation requests.

Comment: OK thanks for the advice.  I've used Routers before, just like you said.  That may be what we need to do here as well.  Thanks again.